# Gson fromJson returning empty JsonObject

Tags: java, json, gson

So, I've got a String that is the result of a toJson method I've implemented on a class, and have confirmed in my test code that it is the correct Json representation of my class.  My goal is to turn this String into a JsonObject and pass it to a constructor, using Gson.  However, I'm running into an odd problem.

This is the code I'm calling:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jObj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
```

I have used literally this exact same snippet of code before in many places in my project, for other classes, and it has worked fine.  I even copied one of those functional snippets of code into this test class and tried it.  However, every version I try results in the same thing--jObj is an empty set of brackets.

I don't understand how it's happening.  I've confirmed that jsonString has all the fields it should need.  Why is Gson returning an empty JsonObject?  No exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: What is the contents of jsonString when you get empty JsonObject?

Comment: the string is "{"varName":1, "otherVarName":2, "thirdVarName":3.4}" and so on.  Typical Json Object

Comment: It's working for me I got the expected output. Please show a small program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What if you add `if (jsonString.trim().isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();` ?

Comment: It doesn't throw the IllegalArgument exception if I add that code.  The string isn't empty at any point--just the JsonObject that gets returned.  Not null, but empty.

Comment: As for a small program demonstrating the problem, that's what I'm trying to figure out--it works for me too, everywhere but this one particularly test case.  I now suspect that the issue may somehow lie in where in my project directory structure the test is--but I have trouble understanding how.  The problem isn't in a reference to any of the other classes in question, it's happening entirely within Gson.fromJson().

Comment: It's hard to help you as we cannot reproduce the problem... Is the parser strict or tolerant? Maybe the string contains some weird non-printable characters.

Comment: All of the fields are plaintext characters, with either integer, boolean, or double values.  No weird characters that I can see.  More to the point, copying code from another part of my project that did work elsewhere no longer works here.  Is there anything in Gson that could be affected just from being instantiated inside a different directory?

Comment: @MichaelHubbard does this part of the project have the same classpath as the places where your code works ? How do you build the project ? If you can do it, visualize your dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so i know this is a little old but I had the same exact issue. The resolution was changing the jar file. I had a similar code sample working in another project but then I was experiencing the exact same problem in another. Well the problem was an older gson-2.1.jar. Updated the problem application to the matching gson-2.3.1.jar and all was working. Hope this helps.

Comment: dang it, you really saved my life !

Answer (score 0):

From your comment that says the string is `{"varName":1, "otherVarName":2, "thirdVarName":3.4}`, looks like the serialized object was a `Map`. You may need to specify the type token:

```
gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Map<K,V>>() {}.getType());
```

where `K` and `V` are the key and value types of the map. If it is not a `Map`, specify whatever class the jsonString was obtained from.

Comment: @Chthonic Project - I believe you're absolutely correct.  To elaborate: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Comment: @MichaelHubbard : added explanation, and the link posted by paulsm4 explains this in detail.

Comment: But the OP is trying to get a `JsonObject` from this `String`, not a `Map`.

Comment: @AlexisC. : As far as I can see, OP has a string that is most probably obtained from a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Yes but as I understand, the issue is the conversion `String -> JsonObject`. This `String` could also come from any other class, not necessarily a `Map`.

Comment: The String does not come from a Map.  It comes from calling Gson.toJson on an Object somewhere else.

Comment: @MichaelHubbard You are converting a node to a string, and then a string to a node ?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I agree. I just went with what seemed to be the most probable class, based on the string example posted by OP in a comment to his question.

Comment: I'm converting an Object to a JsonObject that gets printed to a file, then later coming back and trying to recreate the Object from that JsonObject.  However, in between getting the String and getting the JsonObject I'm running into problems I have never run into before--the exact same lines of code work elsewhere in the program.  I'd say that maybe I put the test in the wrong directory or something, but it's not even referencing another one of my classes--it's entirely in Gson.

Comment: @MichaelHubbard Did you get the solution for this problem ? I am also facing similar issue. When I view my my string on online json parser it is able to recreate jsn object but in code google.Gson() returns empty.

Comment: It ended up being a dependency issue, somehow.  I recommend making sure you are using version 2.3.1 with a scope of "compile", if you're using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was accidentally using the following initializer in my dagger module.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .create()
```

I removed the `setFieldNamingPolicy` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.

I was using

```
return gson.fromJson(response, JsonObject::class.java)
```

And I was receiving an object with only the default values populated.

I had to explicitly define the serialized names for each property in my JsonObject class that was different from how it was named in the json response.

For example, if in the json I was parsing the field name was "total_score', but my JsonObject had a field named "totalProperty", I had to use the @SerialedName annotation to define the relationship.

```
@SerializedName("total_score")
val TotalScore : Int = 0
```